# Listview wont appear

Tags: android, listview

I am new at android and am trying to to make a custom list view that as multiple text view at each of its row.For this i created a custom list adapter by extending ArrayListAdapter and overriding the getView method and set the adapter as list adapater in my main activity.However everytime i run the app listview refuses to populate.

Start.java

```
public class Start extends Activity {
String jasonString="[{\"name\": \"abc\",\n" +
        "\"address\":\"Delhi\",\n" +
        "\"email\":\"abc@gmail.com\"},{\"name\": \"def\",\n" +
        "\"address\":\"Delhi\",\n" +
        "\"email\":\"def@gmail.com\"},{\"name\": \"ghi\",\n" +
        "\"address\":\"ferf\",\n" +
        "\"email\":\"ghi@gmail.com\"},{\"name\": \"jkl\",\n" +
        "\"address\":\"Delheri\",\n" +
        "\"email\":\"jkl@gmail.com\"}\n" +
        ",{\"name\": \"mno\",\n" +
        "\"address\":\"Delhi\",\n" +
        "\"email\":\"mno@gmail.com\"},{\"name\": \"pqr\",\n" +
        "\"address\":\"Delhi\",\n" +
        "\"email\":\"pqr@gmail.com\"}]\n";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i("mee","Activity created.");
    ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    ArrayList<Model> list=new ArrayList<>();
    JsonArray array=new JsonParser().parse(jasonString).getAsJsonArray();
    for(JsonElement element:array){
        Model mod=new Gson().fromJson(element,Model.class);
        list.add(mod);
    }

    Log.i("mee","List size"+list.size());
    for(Model mod:list){
        Log.i("mee", "name:" + mod.name);
    }

    CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this,R.layout.row_item,list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);



        }
   }
```

CustomListAdapter.class

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model>{

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Model> mObjects;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<Model> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mContext=context;
    mObjects=objects;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
      Log.i("meee","inside CustomListAdapter, getView");
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
    }
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(mObjects.get(position).name);
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(mObjects.get(position).address);
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3)).setText(mObjects.get(position).sex);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:text="This is the main layout"/>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list1"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone pls tell me what am i doing wrong? I am not getting any error and the data list always the the data available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main.xml, you have your textview set to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`, so the textview will take up the ENTIRE screen, from top to bottom, leaving no room for the ListView to be shown.

Change it to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code. Change your `main.xml` layout to be as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="This is the main layout"
      />
  <ListView
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:id="@+id/list1"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

It works for me.